ng-select don't open until N characters typed
I have an ng-select which I've configured to use typeahead to perform backend searching as described here: https://medium.com/@sangumallikharjuna/ng-select-typeahead-with-debouncetime-to-fetch-server-response-79dc32fa72a4
<ng-select
    id="search-input"
    [items]="items | async"
    [ngModel]="selectedItem"
    [bindLabel]="bindLabel"
    [bindValue]="bindValue"
    minTermLength="3"
    [typeahead]="searchInput"
    (change)="onSelect($event)"
    (clear)="onClear($event)"
    [loading]="isLoading"
></ng-select>

I don't want the dropdown to open until 3 characters have been typed.  I know I can use the isOpen input, but I don't want to totally override that logic because I still want it to close when items are selected or the user clicks away.  Is there anyway to achieve this?

There is one input minTermLength in ng-select for Minimum term length to start a search.
Add [minTermLength]="3" to start search on minimum 3 term. Ex.
<ng-select
    id="search-input"
    [items]="items | async"
    [ngModel]="selectedItem"
    [bindLabel]="bindLabel"
    [bindValue]="bindValue"
    minTermLength="3"
    [typeahead]="searchInput"
    [minTermLength]="3"
    (change)="onSelect($event)"
    (clear)="onClear($event)"
    [loading]="isLoading"
></ng-select>

stackblitz
Referance ng-select

That was in my original post and doesn’t seem to work?  I’m assuming that determines if the search function is called, rather than if the dropdown is open?  As when I click the select, the dropdown opens with no found items

add typeToSearchText="Type 3 char to search" so it did not show no found items until you type 3 char. show stackbiltz example

That still displays the dropdown, it just puts the text 'Type 3 char to search' into the dropdown.  I need to dropdown to not open at all until 3 characters have been entered

ng-select doesn't provide that functionality.
You have to treat it manually by using [isOpen] and (search).
